# FailedGetExternalMetric Warning for selenium KEDA- Unable to get external metric

Tags: kubernetes, selenium-webdriver, keda

I am using selenium KEDA for auto-scaling. When I check the HPA logs - it says FAILED to get a Metrics error.
Can someone please guide me about the issue here?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the following commnads output:

**kubectl get pod -n custom-metrics,

kubectl logs pod/<pod-name-from-above-cmd> -n custom-metrics > out.log,

kubectl get --raw "/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io",

kubectl api-resources | grep -i metric,

kubectl get svc -A,

kubectl get apiservices | grep metrics.k8s.io.**

Comment: Inspect the YAML of the **custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter**. Check the yaml and image being used and compare it to the OSS YAML and check if you see any differences.

If the image is different or older than the OSS YAML, then match the version and try again. Refer to the similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67073909),which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: There is no custom-metrics namespace. Everything is under the default namespace.
Here the K8s files -> https://github.com/DeepKandey/POMFramework/tree/master/k8s

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue. The problem was in the selenium graphql URL that I was using in the KEDA scaled object yaml
I needed to append the namespace in the URL. And that did the trick.

apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
name: selenium-chrome-scaledobject
namespace: default
labels:
deploymentName: selenium-node-chrome
spec:
minReplicaCount: 0
maxReplicaCount: 8
scaleTargetRef:
name:  node-chrome-deployment
triggers:
- type: selenium-grid
metadata:
url: 'http://selenium-hub.default:4444/graphql'
browserName: 'chrome'
unsafeSsl : 'true'